# search multiple keywords from text files, and format output

Tags: grep, text-search

I am having trouble with the following problem:

say I have a list of words that I would like to search from multiple text files;
e.g. in keywords.txt, I have:

```
    word1
    word2
    word3
```

I'd like to search each individual keyword in a number of other text files. Hopefully, the output of the search can be formatted like this:

```
Keyword                        Sentence

word1                          This sentence contains word1.
word1                          This paragraph also contains word1.
word2                          word2 does not exist in this file.
```

In other words, I am hoping to sort the output based on keyword.

I made a little progress using grep, but I am not sure about: 1) how to sort the grep output based on keywords; 2) how to output the entire sentence, as opposed to only the line that contains the keyword (which is the default behavior of grep).

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show how you used `grep`? You may be almost there

Comment: @fedorqui I did: grep -f keywords.txt textfile.txt